# Slide down an AdView when an ad is received

Tags: ios, three20, adwhirl

I've got a navigation controller with a view and a navigation bar.
I want to insert an AdView (I'm using AdWhirl) between the navbar and the view.
The AdView should slide down and push the view down (the view must resize itself, not going offscreen).

I'm working with Three20 if this matters.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Three20 but I could tell you how I'd normally do it. You would want to write this code in `adWhirlDidReceiveAd:` (assuming that you have read the tutorials on setting the correct delegate here and overriding that method, and that your ad view is a subview of the current view in your navigation controller).

So in `adWhirlDidReceiveAd:`, you want to slide down your content (this is the view that's in you navigation controller) and slide in the ad that you receive.

```
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView_ {


  CGSize adSize = [adWhirlView_ actualAdSize];
  CGRect newFrame = adWhirlView_.frame;

  newFrame.size = adSize;
  newFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/ 2;

  //Draw offscreen so that it can slide in properly
  CGRect tempFrame = newFrame;
  tempFrame.origin.y = -newFrame.size.height;
  adWhirlView_.frame = tempFrame;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
       //Access frame of view controller in nav controller 
       CGRect viewFrame = [self.navigationController topViewController].view.frame;

       // Decrease the height of the view by the height of the adwhirlView
       viewFrame.size.height = [self.navigationController topViewController].view.frame.size.height -
                        adwhirlView_.frame.size.height;
       // Shift view down to make room for the ad
       viewFrame.origin.y = adwhirlView_.frame.size.height;

       [self.navigationController topViewController].view.frame = viewFrame;

       //Slide down the ad
       adwhirlView_.frame = frame;

  }];

}
```

You probably want to check if the first ad has already come in as well so you don't do the slide transition every time an ad comes in.

I'm pretty sure you could clean the code up I have there a lot as well, just wanted to throw my thoughts down while I could.

Comment: Seems legit ^^
Will try that :)